# Silverlight: How to debug dynamically loaded assemblies efficiently?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, silverlight-4.0, .net-assembly

I dynamically load Silverlight class library projects on demand. (DLLs in a zip).

This is not the problem...the problem seems to be that I have to **manually** copy the pdb file(s) of those loaded assemblies (the assemblies belong all to the same VS solution) into the debug(output) folder of the main Silverlight application for debugging. If I don't do this, Visual Studio does not hold on breakpoints of those dynamically loaded assemblies.

I really hope I make something wrong here and not that I have to create a post-build script, which does that 'copy pdb job'.

Thanks for feedback.

Comment: Hi. I am having the same problem. Even worse, if I manually copy the dll + pdb files than the breakpoint is colored in full red but is still not hit. Have you discovered anything 'new'?

Comment: no, for the time being I have disabled the dynamic loading of dlls...but have to revisit this topic also later...